# How to pass value to a onclick function in (Jade)pug?

Tags: javascript, pug

I am new to jade and stuck on this issue. I think I have tried everything from the StackOverflow posts and still at nothing.

The things I have tried

```
button(type='button' class=' c-btn-blue c-btn-circle c-btn-uppercase' value="Read More" onclick='gotoBlog( #{val.link} )')
```

Error

```
1:8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Changing it to `!{val.link}`

Error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

Changing it to `"!{val.link}"` and `"#{val.link}"` just gives me string understandably so. BTW val.link is a string

Just giving val.link says `Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined`

I am out of options now. Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you setting/defining `val`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When adding attributes to an html element, you are already within the scope of pug, so you can just use pug variables like regular js variables.

```
button(type='button' class=' c-btn-blue c-btn-circle c-btn-uppercase' value="Read More" onclick='gotoBlog(' + val.link + ')')
```

Answer (score 9):

I've just used the code with **pre** and **pos quotes** and it worked:

```
button(type='button', onclick='someFunction("'+ yourObject.id +'")' ) PressMe
```

Comment: only this solution worked with me

Answer (score 2):

You just need to put onclick="myfunction(#{varible.atributo})"

Here a example:

```
table
thead
    tr
        th #ID
        th Description
        th Actions
tbody
    each item, i in itemlist
        tr
            th(scope='row') #{item.id}
            td #{item.description}
            td
                button(onclick="editItem(#{item.id})", title="Edit")
                    |  Edit
```

Answer (score 2):

Use differing nested quotation marks so that you pass a string to your gotoBlog function.  Here, I use single ticks within double ticks.

```
button(type='button' class=' c-btn-blue c-btn-circle c-btn-uppercase' value="Read More" onclick="gotoBlog( '#{val.link}' )")
```

In other words:

```
button( onclick= "myFunction('#{stringVariable}')" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Too late, I know :(

But, this could be useful!

```
`${}`
```

So the code will be

```
button(type='button' class=' c-btn-blue c-btn-circle c-btn-uppercase' value="Read More" onclick=`gotoBlog( ${val.link} )`)
```

Answer (score 2):

Too late but most of the options above didn't work for me but this did

```
button(onclick='gotoBlog('+'"'+val.link+'"'+')')
```

or simpler:

```
onclick=`gotoBlog('${val.link}')`
```

Basically converts val.link to a string.

Comment: I also found the answers above did not work for me, yours did, thanks

Comment: This is the one...

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar issues and solved it rather differently (by escaping params). 
In my case, I needed to pass the following `template values` to a javascript function as argument when a button is clicked

```
{
  url:"http://google.com",
  token: "Bearer your-token", 
  accountId: "abc123"
}
```

So the `pug` in my case looked as follow

```
button(onclick='authenticate(\'' + url + '\',\'' + token + '\',\'' + accountId + '\')') Login
```

And the resulting html is as follow

```
<button onclick="authenticate('http://google.com','Bearer your-token','abc123')">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When using multiple parameters in a function, this did the trick:

`'myFunction(' + '"' + varA + '"' + ',' + '"' + varB + '"' + ')'`

NOTE: outer/inner/all quote marks can be `'` (single) or `"` (double) quote marks, I used single and double quote marks for readability.

Answer (score 0):

button(type='button', onClick='function(\'' + someValue + '\')') Text

This worked for me to use values that I passed to pug inside an onClick function.