# Pug / Jade : onClick call function and pass param

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

## Demo code here : https://codepen.io/iShawnWang/pen/ZvBGRv

All i want is to call a js function and pass a param,
I have tried the following answer, but not works

- [How to pass value to a onclick function in (Jade)pug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160264/how-to-pass-value-to-a-onclick-function-in-jadepug)

And as discussed in the Pug Github issues below,

- [Pass Object from Jade to function](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2101)

`Event handlers like onclick can only be added through HTML or client-side JavaScript. This is not something Jade can help you with.`

So what is the best practice to add onclick listener on Pug template ?

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by myself : https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2933

```
a.postTitle(onclick=`viewPost(${JSON.stringify(file)})`)= file.name
```

then, I can receive an object at `viewPost` function,
**take care of the ` symbol**

Answer (score 0):

**So what is the best practice to add onclick listener on Pug template ?**

From my own experiences, I recommend adding `script` tag with the event handler logic to the template, and declaring the `onclick` without any backticks, grave-accents, string-interpolation marks:

```
`
```

String interpolation marks will fail with some UglifyJs build steps (usually common in Prod configurations):

`this-will-${fail}-in-some-UglifyJs-versions`

An example of what I mean would look like this:

```
// my template.pug

script
  function myFunction(varA, varB){
    // do something...
  }

- var someVar = "this is a string, but the value could come from anywhere, really"

div(onclick='myFunction(' + '"' + someVar + '"' + ',' + '"' + someVar + '"' + ')')
```

[The linked question now covers this in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52175291/5273418).