# Passing Values to onclick button Pug

Tags: javascript, onclick, attributes, pug

I am trying to pass a js function to a button using Pug. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39160264/how-to-pass-value-to-a-onclick-function-in-jadepug) here, but it does not seem to cover how to format the js function.

I could not find documentation explaining how to do this, but perhaps it is on pug.org and I just do not understand it. Any links to documentation/ an explanation would be great.

Anyway, I had the following:

```
extends layout

block content
 h1=title
  -var itemNumber= 1;
  -function add_fields() {
    -itemNumber++;
    -var objTo = document.getElementById('incomeItems');
    -var divtest = document.createElement("div");
    -divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Item ' + itemNumber +':</div><div class="content"><span>Item Name: <input type="text" style="width:150px;" name="itemName[]" value="" /><small></small></span><span> Income Amount: <input type="number" style="width:60px;" namae="itemAmount[]" value="" /><small></small></span></div>';
    -objTo.appendChild(divtest);
  -}

  form(method='POST' action='')
    div.form-group
      label(for='name') Budget Name:
      input#budget_name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Such as: New Building Budget' name='name' required='true' value=(undefined===budget ? '' : budget.name) )
    div.form-group#incomeItems
      label(for='income') Income:
      input#income.form-control(type='number', name='income' required='true' value=(undefined===budget ? '' : budget.income) )
  button.btn.btn-primary(type='button' onclick='add_fields()') Add Income Item
    div.form-group
      label(for='expenses') Expenses:
      input#expenses.form-control(type='number', name='expenses' required='true' value=(undefined===budget ? '' : budget.expenses) )
button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit

if errors 
  ul
    for error in errors
      li!= error.msg
```

I was only able to get it to work using `script.` (which maybe is fine but I thought perhaps was not the best way to approach this?)

```
extends layout

block content
 h1=title
 script.
      var itemNumber= 1;
      function add_fields() {
          itemNumber++;
          var objTo = document.getElementById('incomeItems');
          var divtest = document.createElement("div");
      divtest.innerHTML = '<div class="label">Item ' + itemNumber +':</div><div class="content"><span>Item Name: <input type="text" style="width:150px;" name="itemName[]" value="" /><small></small></span><span> Income Amount: <input type="number" style="width:60px;" namae="itemAmount[]" value="" /><small></small></span></div>';
      objTo.appendChild(divtest);
  }

  form(method='POST' action='')
    div.form-group
      label(for='name') Budget Name:
      input#budget_name.form-control(type='text', placeholder='Such as: New Building Budget' name='name' required='true' value=(undefined===budget ? '' : budget.name) )
    div.form-group#incomeItems
      label(for='income') Income:
      input#income.form-control(type='number', name='income' required='true' value=(undefined===budget ? '' : budget.income) )
  button.btn.btn-primary(type='button' onclick='add_fields()') Add Income Item
    div.form-group
      label(for='expenses') Expenses:
      input#expenses.form-control(type='number', name='expenses' required='true' value=(undefined===budget ? '' : budget.expenses) )
button.btn.btn-primary(type='submit') Submit

if errors 
  ul
    for error in errors
      li!= error.msg
```

I could not find the `script.` at https://pugjs.org/language/code.html , so I am not sure how I was supposed to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

It is perfectly fine to write your client-side JavaScript/jQuery code inside `.script`. The JavaScript code you write using `'-' at the beginning of a line` is supposed to be run server-side, when the Jade/Pug is being compiled to produce the resulting html. So, you can write here code like when you want to loop through an array etc. and create some corresponding html structure for each item in the array. Please notice that this is being done on the server side, this looping code won't anywhere be found in the html file that's being sent to browser.

But, the `script` code is intended to end up in the html file in the browser and to get executed there only. So, it's perfectly fine to put it inside `.script` which just places the contained code as it is inside `<script></script>` tags in the resulting html file.